# Ordinary least squares input - provide average and uncertainty vs all data

Tags: python, least-squares

Assume any linear model (sth like this):
$y=a*x + c + \epsilon$

And some measurements $Y$ for a set of fixed points $x\in{[1,2,3,..]}$ where there are multiple measurements $y_i$ for a given point in $x$, i.e. for $x=1$ there are $y$ values [1,2,3..] and so on.

Does it matter for the least squares algorithm, whether I provide the the measurement data $Y$ as $\mu+-\sigma$ for each $y_i$  compared to providing the measurements directly?

My minimal example shows slight differences but (probably because its too simple) I dont know if this is based on how the solver handles the data input or due to different assumptions between providing the full data and µ+sd.

Since this is my first question here, I would also appreciate you commenting how I should improve the questioning style in the future!

Minimal example:

````
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import numpy as np

def residual(variables, x, data, eps_data):
    """fit model to data"""
    m = variables[0]
    b = variables[1]
    model = m*x+b
    return (data-model) / eps_data

# generate synthetic data with noise
x = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3])
np.random.seed(0)
y = x*2 + 0.5 + np.random.normal(0,0.1, len(x))

# fit data to linear model
variables = [1.0,1.0]
eps_data = np.ones_like(x)
out1 = leastsq(residual, variables, args=(x, y, eps_data))
print(out1)

# do the same fit but using avg + sd as input
y_sd = np.array([np.std(y[:6]), np.std(y[6:12]),np.std(y[12:18])])
y_avg = np.array([np.mean(y[:6]), np.mean(y[6:12]), np.mean(y[12:18])])
x_avg = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
out2 = leastsq(residual, variables, args=(x_avg, y_avg, y_sd))
print(out2)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your question, and welcome to the forum! Am I correct in understanding that your inputs to the regression model are noisy? In this case it is very likely that you are dealing with a [errors in variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) problem. While providing code is already helpful, stating your problem with some equations if possible, would be even better.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that topic! however, my measurement error is only in the dependent variable. As far as I understand, the "errors in variables" problem focuses on uncertainty in the independent variable.

Comment: Sorry! I don't know how I managed to totally misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to account for error measuments in the y-values is [weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares). Seeing however that all y-values are corrupted by noise of the **same** standard deviation (0.1 in your code), standard least squares should return the same solution in this case.

It seems that what you are doing in your second call to least squares, is replacing the y-values that come from the same x-values by their average. This of course will suppress the noise on them and will most likely lead to a better estimation as the averaged y-values are expected to be closer to the "true" y-values, i.e. the y-values before adding noise on them.

Here, however, you should not notice any difference between your two solutions as the standard deviation of the noise is the same for all y-values. I guess the difference you observe, is purely down to numerics, as you are passing slightly different values to the solver. Perhaps it is worth trying out repeating the experiment with standard deviations that are different for each observed y-value.

---

I am neither familiar with python nor the `leastsq` function, so I am not entirely sure what they should exactly deliver for your inputs.

Comment: thanks! It seems like I dont have the rep. to accept this as answer - even though I posted the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Very unusual you can't accept the answer, but don't worry about it;)